# Writing comparison to .txt file when comparing sql files

Tags: python, writer

So I'm trying to compare multiple tables using a Python script. The actual comparison is working, tested with print statements, but the write to a .txt file is not. I believe I might have an error in my syntax, though being relatively new to Python, I can't find it.

```
for num in range(0, 4): #runs through the database array and compares the files in each folder
    comp_var = directory + server_number[size] + databases[num]
    for file in os.listdir(comp_var):     
        for num1 in  os.listdir(master + databases[num]):  
            var = master + databases[num] + "\\" + os.listdir(master + databases[num])[size]
            for line in open(var, 'r'):
                for line2 in open(comp_var + "\\" + file, 'r'):
                    same = set(line).intersection(line2)
                    print(same)
                same.discard('\n')
            with open('results.txt', 'w') as file_out:
                for line1 in same:
                    file_out.write(line1)
            size = size + 1
            comp_var = directory + server_number[size] + databases[num]            
        size = 0
```

Comment: Can you describe what's happening? Do you get an error message? Is the file created at all?

Comment: @Dag the file is created, there is no error message except when it reaches a file in another folder that it can't find. Other than that it shoul be writing line by line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you create a new file every time you call open. You should use 'a' to append to a file, which is probably what you want.

Comment: Or even better open the file in `'w'` mode outside of the outermost loop...

Comment: Try to print the output that you are writing to the file as a debugging measure. This means printing line1. Additionally the intendation seems wrong.

Comment: And opening the file in {'w'} mode outside the outermost loop produces nothing except an infinite loop

Comment: How so? (re indentation)

Comment: You probably want to write out the data that you are printing. However you are setting the same variable in every iteration of the for loop. You probably want same to be a list and append the text you are generating.

Comment: I'll try that now

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the `results.txt`.

`with open('results.txt', 'w') as file_out:`

change it to:

`with open('results.txt', 'a') as file_out:`

from [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html):

> `'w'` for only writing (an existing file with the same name will be erased), and `'a'` opens the file for appending; any data written to the file is automatically added to the end.